# How to restart a long python script at breakpoint multiple times without rerunning

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to set a kind of breakpoint to a line in python. Then i start developing further code and while testing it, i want to debug it from the breakpoint beginning and not have to run the whole script before the breakpoint everytime.

Is this functionality provided by the python debugger? (and also in the Pycharm IDE?)

Comment: You might want to consider breaking up your script into smaller parts and unit test each of these smaller parts separately.

Comment: Yes this is of course always possible. Also with the pickle module you can do many things. But i was a bit curious since this seems to me to be a useful feature for many scripts that run a long time, but i could not find information on this.

Comment: Unfortunately Python does not have a similar implementation like `Goto` that skip sections of codes.  It's probably best to separate your code as mentioned or you'll need to set several debug flags within your code.  I would recommend the first approach.